# VBA loop through price scale

Tags: ms-access, vba

It seems to be a very easy question but momentarely I totally fail.

I have a table with ID, ArticleNumber, Quantity, Price

```
1 2 0  5
2 2 1000 3
3 2 5000 2
4 2 10000 1
```

The price rule is that up to 999 the price is 5, between 1000 and 4999 the price is 3, between 5000 and 9999 the price is 2 and from 10000 the price is 1.

How can I make this work? Considering that further intermediate price staps are neccessary.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Use the native function `Switch`. Exactly for such scenarios.

Comment: Neither if then, select case or in my opinion switch is suitable, because then the values can't be variable.

Comment: You didn't tell, that they were to change, only that intermediate values could be added. But then, just look up the highest value lower than the price.

Comment: Clarifying: You want to automatically make the Price hardwire itself based on the quantity for all future records created? Do you also have potential incorrect existing records that need to be amended? Is a Data Macro out of the question, checking and updating records as they are added to the table?

Answer (score 2):

Without error checking:

```
Function GetPrice(Article, Quantity) as Variant
    Dim sSQL as String
    Dim rRST as RecordSet

    sSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 Price FROM Table WHERE ArticleNumber = " & Article & " AND Quantity <= " & Quantity & " ORDER BY Quantity DESC;"
    Set rRST = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
    if rRST.RecordCount > 0 then GetPrice = rRST!Price
End Function
```

(Edited following Andre comment)

Comment: Note that `rRST.MoveFirst` is superfluous. After opening a recordset, it's either EOF or on the first record.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after a short break I got clear and found the solution:

```
strsql = "SELECT * from tblpricescale where ProdID = " & lngProdID & " Order by quantity"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql, dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)
If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        dblPrice = rs("price")

        If lngQuantity >= rs("Quantity") Then
            dblPricekorr = dblPrice
            dblFinalPrice = dblPricekorr 
        Else
            dblFinalPrice = dblPricekorr 

        End If

        rs.MoveNext

    Loop
    End If
```